# A verb for regulation in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests

> When he was a deputy minister, he contributed to ————— the
> problematic regulations.

I am looking for a verb for regulation in the above context.

**I want to say that such regulations were not there before him, but he made them be, initiated them, imposed them, put them forth, or lay them down. So he is responsible for the regulations. And the problematic regulations are still there.**

*The establishment of, establishing, the introduction of,* come to my mind but I am not sure about them.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is slightly vague, I am thinking ***institute*** matches your sentence:

> to start or cause a system, rule, legal action, etc. to exist ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/institute))

and

> introduce or establish (a scheme, undertaking, or policy).([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=institute%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsbGfCMzRwa0bhUg8XuzPMJJJReM3w%3A1661080327506&ei=BxMCY922HsydgQbpjKr4AQ&ved=0ahUKEwid1vS25tf5AhXMTsAKHWmGCh8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=institute%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-QEyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CAgAELEDEJECOgQIABBDOgUIABCRAjoHCAAQsQMQQzoHCAAQgAQQCjoMCCMQsQIQJxBGEPkBSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUJ0IWMoXYLkeaAJwAXgAgAFmiAGcBpIBAzkuMZgBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

So your sentence would be

> When he was a deputy minister, he contributed to ***institute*** the problematic regulations.

One can also ***promulgate regulations***:

> to put (a law or rule) into action or force ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promulgate))

Comment: Or to ‘instituting’ or ‘the institution of’?

Comment: Yes, you can use the verb as you see fit. Both your suggestions are correct. Note that _instituting_ would be used as a gerund (noun), and _institution_ is clearly a noun. However, you asked for a verb.